# Jquery: remove a dom ele after its been appended

Tags: jquery, dom

Yo!

I am building a content builder which allows you to append an html block which has form elements in it. eg: wysiwyg, textarea etc

This is working well. I can add and save the form nicely. However, I have a remove btn on that removes the particular element from the array. If I save and use the remove btn it works well.

#### Question

How do I remove an element that has only just been appended to the dom?

Here is what I have:

```
$('.remove-content').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this item?')) {
        $(this).closest('.dd-item').remove();
    }
});

// Link
<a href="#" class="remove-content"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

As mentioned, this works for elements loaded normally, but if I 'append' the dom with a fresh element, the function doesn't run and I just get /#'d

Cheers guys

Comment: You would do well to show us your HTML or to create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) at this context,

```
$(document).on('click','.remove-content', function(e) {
```

And in the place of `document` please use any other `static` parent to the element with the class `remove-content`

Comment: Ahhhh. Jackpot. Schoolboy basics. Thanks very much. Works well. I'll mark as correct and +1 after the StackExchange limit is up. Many thanks Rajaprabhu. You are a star!